# Method chaining with reusable charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, closures, chaining

I am getting an error thrown `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` when attempting to chain methods with my d3 chart following the principles [from Mike](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/). My chart looks something like

```
 function generateTimeline() {
     var width = 800;
     ...
     function timeline(selection) {
        ...
     }
    timeline.width = function(_) {
        if(!arguments.length) return width;
        width = _;
        return chart;
    }
    return chart
 }
```

And I can call

```
    var chart = generateTimeline();

    d3.select('body')
        .datum(dataSet)
        .call(chart);
```

which generates a chart properly. I can even call `chart.width()` which returns 800. However, on attempting with

```
var chart = generateTimeline().width(600)

d3.select('body')
    .datum(dataSet)
    .call(chart);
```

the error is thrown. I should note that the error is not thrown until attempting to `call(chart)`.

Comment: What is `chart` in `generateTimeline()`?

Comment: perfect, thanks Lars! should be timeline

Comment: Wait, did that solve it?